# How can I build a function that stores data in a structure when taken from a file (pointer)?

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures

In an assignment I'm working on, I need to read data from a file and then convert that data into a form that can be stored in a structure. The structure stores information on the person the line in the file represents. The issue that I'm having is that I cannot find a way to build a function that will allow me to take this data and store it in the structure. This is the relevant code to getting the file:

```
    FILE* ifp;
    char file_name[150], early_type[5], name_holder[LENGTH];
    double early_registration, indi_registration, team_registration, amount_holder;
    int num_early_regist, age_holder, type_holder;

    // get file name and set it up as a pointer
    printf("Please enter the name of your file.\n");
    scanf("%s", file_name);

    ifp = fopen(file_name, "r");
```

The code then goes to scanning the file for the data:

```
fscanf(ifp, "%s %s %d %d %lf", early_type, name_holder, &age_holder, &type_holder, &amount_holder);
        // if the line shows an individual registering early
        if (strcmp(early_type, "INDV")==0){
            person_early(struct person* person, &name_holder, &age_holder, &type_holder, &amount_holder);
        }
```

Finally, this is the prototype of the function that I am building:

```
void person_early(struct person* person, char* name[LENGTH], int* age, int* event_type, double* donation_amount);
```

The issue that I'm having is that I'm not sure how to put the data into this structure:

```
struct person {
    char name[LENGTH];
    int number;
    int age;
    int event;
    float money;
    float time;
};
```

Should I build a function to store this data, as there are several people to log from the file? Do I need to be using pass by value or pass by reference? Thanks for any help.

Edit:

The full function that I have written is this:

```
void person_early(struct person* person, char* name[LENGTH], int* age, int* event_type, double* donation_amount) {
    // the name of the variable should be the name that is taken from the file
    struct person (*name[LENGTH]);

    (*name).name = *name_holder;
    (*name).age = *age_holder;
    (*name).event = *type_holder;
    (*name).money = *donation_amount;


    return;
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. "Should I build a function to store this data". Yes of course. Isn't that what `person_early` is supposed to be for? "Do I need to be using pass by value or pass by reference". C does not have any pass by reference. You need to pass in a pointer to a variable of `struct person` exactly as shown by the function prototype. It's difficult to understand what specific problem you have.

Comment: You need to first have a variable of type `struct person`. Then pass the address of that variable (ie pointer) to the `person_early` function. It is not clear from your question whether the file has data for a single person or many people. In practice it will be many entries so you need to allocate enough memory to store each person (can start with an array though I don't know what your requirements are).

Comment: @kaylum Thanks for the tip. The file has multiple people, upwards of a dozen. The issue that I'm having is that when I try to take a variable declaring the type of the structure, for instance, structure person Jason, I get an issue. I want the variable to equal the name of the person in the file. So, for instance, if the person's name is Sam, I want to be able to store data like Sam.name, Sam. age, etc.. This can should be repeated for all names. The issue is I try
```
struct person name[LENGTH]
```
but it does not do that.

Comment: You need to declare an array of `struct person`. e.g. `struct person my_person_aray[MAX_NUM_PEOPLE];`

Comment: OT: regarding: `scanf("%s", file_name);`  1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  Note: the `scanf()` family of functions returns the number of successful 'input format conversion specifiers'  Suggest:  `if( `scanf("%s", file_name) != 1 ) { fprintf( stderr, "scanf for file name failed\n" );  exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }`   Note `exit()` and `EXIT_FAILURE` are exposed in the `stdlib.h` header file

Comment: regarding: `(*name).name = *name_holder;`  this will not copy the name read from the file into the field `.name` in the struct.  Suggest: `strcpy( (*name).name, name_holder );`   Thsi technique needs to be applied to any array.  However, individual 'base' types (like `int`) can be directly assigned

Comment: in C, cannot set a variable name from an array of characters input from the 'outside' world

Comment: in the `person_early()` function, those parameters that are simple base C types can be directly passed by value, no need to pass a pointer

Comment: regarding: `fscanf(ifp, "%s %s %d %d %lf",`  1) note prior comment about checking the returned value.  2) when using `%s` and/or `%[...]` always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer because those specifiers always append a NUL byte to the input.  This also avoids any possibility of a buffer overflow and the resulting undefined behavior

Comment: in the signature for the function: `persons_early()` this parameter: `char* name[LENGTH],` is declaring `name[]` to be an array of pointers to char.   Probably not what you want.

Comment: regarding: `person_early(struct person* person, &name_holder, &age_holder, &type_holder, &amount_holder);`  The `person` parameter needs to be a pointer, however, none of the other parameters need to be prefixed by `&`.  Then the actual variable values will be passed, except the `name_holder` which is an array pointer.  Note: in C, a bare reference to an array name (as this is doing) will degrade to the address of the first byte of the array so no `&` is needed (and it would be an error to use `&`

Answer (score 0):

regarding:

```
(*name).name = *name_holder;
```

This is not what you want.   The passed in struct pointer `person` is the receiver of all the data.  suggest:

```
void person_early( struct person* person, char name[], int age, int event_type, double donation_amount) 
{
    strcpy( person->name, name );
    person->age   = age;
    person->event = event_type;
    person->money = donation_amount;
}
```

Note: no `return` needed on a `void` function, unless exiting before the end of the function